# Programmatic event handling JavaScript with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner to JavaScript. I've been testing my code while learning, but while trying out a few examples with programmatic event handling, I've had a few issues. For some reason the following snippet doesn't seem to work. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>DOM Interactions</title> 
<script>
   var b = document.getElementById("btn");
   b.addEventListener("click", handler);


   function handler(){
   var x = document.getElementById("TextChange");
   x.innerHTML = "Changed text with programmatic event handling!";
  }

</script>
<body>
     <p id="TextChange">This will change!</p>
     <button id="btn">Click!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried it and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/2aYtv/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/ninuzeqa/1/edit

DOM in not yet read.  Simply place your `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script>
   var b = document.getElementById("btn");
   b.addEventListener("click", handler);


   function handler(){
   var x = document.getElementById("TextChange");
   x.innerHTML = "Changed text with programmatic event handling!";
  }

  </script>  
</body>
```